# lab PSU based on a single power amplifier?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, power-amplifier

[OPA548](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/texasinstruments/opa548.pdf) op amp is a power amplifier capable of delivering 3 A at the output and limiting the current. at page 14 of the [datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/texasinstruments/opa548.pdf) (figure 16) shows the schematic of a variable power supply based on OPA548.

I've never seen any commercial power supply based on a single power amplifier, while it makes sense to build such power supply to keep the cost low.

What are the disadvantages of building such power supply? why it isn't used in commercial PSUs?

Comment: It has probably build in power stage for applications like motor drivers, audio amplifiers etc. I think it's something specific. I don't think it could replace a general purpose commercial PSU. In addition it's a linear power supply. Not a dc to dc converter which has big loss in that power.

Comment: @MrBit In first page of the datasheet, power supply is mentioned in applications next to motor driver etc. in the market most PSUs are linear, why it couldn't replace a commercial PSU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the schematic of a typical inexpensive bench power supply (from Dave Jones' [EEVBLOG](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/manson-velleman-etc-ps-613-bench-power-supply-repair-schematics-needed/)):

[image]

This is an example of a real product, a mature one, where cost has been pared to a minimum for the desired level of functionality and performance.

Most of the functionality of the outrageously expensive OPA548 power op-amp is performed by a couple 2-cent op-amps and a few pennies worth of power transistors (Q1, Q3, U1A/B). Note the two relays which control the AC input to BR1 in order to keep the linear power supply dissipation within reason.

Note also the substantial output filtering of C6||C7. The OPA548 is not stable with more than about 1000pF on the output, so there would have be additional components added to prevent it from oscillating if you want the AC output impedance to be low. The OPA548 also has no reference, so it has to be added. And no way to control a fan, so a temperature sensor is required unless you want the fan screaming all the time. This power supply goes all the way down to 0V (not 120mV). Etc.

Answer (score 3):

> *What are the disadvantages of building such power supply? why it isn't
>   used in commercial PSUs?*

[image]

It's a linear power supply with an input power rail of 30 volts and capable of delivering 5 amps at a variable output voltage. What if that variable output voltage was set to be (say) 15 volts. The output current being 5 amps means that the output power is 75 watts (not bad) but the power into the circuit is 30 volts x 5 amps (and maybe a tad more for biasing) and this equals maybe 160 watts.

That's 85 watts being generated as heat so, in this modern world, nobody's going to do that when you can make a buck-linear supply of maybe 85% efficiency. It's even worse if your output was set to 1.2 volts; nearly 160 watts would be given off as heat.

The Burr Brown data sheet you linked was written in 1997 and although that same circuit appears in the TI data sheet for 2019, nobody's going to build it in quantity (especially as they are circa $15 each in small quantity and likely to go obsolete in the next few years).